# Incomplete turtlebot model on fuerte gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, turtlebot, ros-fuerte, turtlebot-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know questions like this have already come up ([here](http://answers.ros.org/question/52995/state-of-turtlebot-simulation-using-gazebo-in-fuerte-and-groovy/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/38465/fuerte-turtlebot-simulator-ubuntu-1204-precise/)). Since I am yet to get a clear solution, I am re-posting. I face the following problems:

**Incomplete model of the TurtleBot**.

From [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/38465/fuerte-turtlebot-simulator-ubuntu-1204-precise/), I found that by uncommenting a part of the code in turtlebot_body.urdf.xacro, one can see the complete model of the robot instead of just 2 wheels. After uncommenting the part, I was able to the complete model of the robot in the empty.world but in the world that I built. I am still seeing just two wheels in my world. Does this problem still persist? Is there a solution ?

**RaySensor warning.**

My gazebo shell in spammed with `Warning [RaySensor.cc:206] ranges not constructed yet (zero sized)` when I spawn the TurtleBot. I searched for the file which has this line and comment it, but without any luck. Though this isn't a major issue, it still is irritating.

I am running ROS-Fuerte on Unbuntu 12.04.

Thanks,

Prasanna

P.S: I know this could be posted in gazebosim forum. I hope some ROS enthusiasts might help me here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58114/incomplete-turtlebot-model-on-fuerte-gazebo/) by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1363 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Besides launching Gazebo and robot.launch at the same time I've found two (very hacky) solutions to the problem of an incomplete Turtlebot model in Fuerte.

---

**Solution 1**

After launching `turtlebot_world.launch` and adding the turtlebot, close the GUI. This should not close the Gazebo server, just the GUI component.

Now you can re-open the GUI from another terminal window by typing `rosrun gazebo gui`. This will not work every time, but I find that after relaunching the GUI window a few times the entire turtlebot appears.

---

**Solution 2**

Find the Turtlebot URDF file

```
roscd turtlebot_description/urdf
```

Now modify the turtlebot urdf to remove the "hardware" (supports and such).

```
vim turtlebot.urdf.xarcro
```

Comment out the line that includes the hardware urdf file - the result should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="turtlebot"
       xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
       xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
       xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
       xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">
    <!--
    <include filename="$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot_hardware.urdf.xacro" />
    -->
    <include filename="$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot_body.urdf.xacro" />
    <include filename="$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot_calibration.xacro" />
    <include filename="$(find turtlebot_description)/urdf/turtlebot_kinect.urdf.xacro" />

    <property name="M_PI" value="3.14159"/>  <property name="SCALE" value="0.0254"/>

    <!-- Body of TurtleBot, with plates, standoffs and Create (including sim sensors) -->
    <turtlebot_body/>

    <!-- Kinect frames and mounting (includes simulation) -->
    <turtlebot_kinect/>
</robot>
```

Note that this will result in the turtlebot being rendered without standoffs between the plates, however the simulation seems to work just fine without these.

---

Originally posted by [abencz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1851/abencz/) with karma: 83 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-04-24**:
@abencz Excellent! Awesome! I tried your first solution and it worked. Thanks a lot :-) I do not have the option of giving 10 up-votes! I will try the second one and get back.